# Replacing Gherkin within Specflow

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, specflow, gherkin

We have just decided to use Specflow in our .Net MVC projects.

Is there any way we can replace the language currently used i.e. Gherkin with any alternative language? Are there any alternatives available?

Cheers,

Hasan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your meaning of "alternative language" is **localisation** (i.e. translate "given", "when", "then", "in order to" .. to german "Angenommen", "Wenn", "Dann", ....) you can do it in the config file

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow"/>
  </configSections>
  <specFlow>
    <language feature="de-DE" tool="" />
  </specFlow>
</configuration>
```

For details see [Make SpecFlow / Cuke4VS understand non-English .feature files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529222/make-specflow-cuke4vs-understand-non-english-feature-files)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible to use an alternative language within specflow.

I'm not sure why you would want to replace Gherkin, i've found that by using Gherkin the business have been able to give valuable input into the test cases that are created and run, This is due to the Gherkin language being very human readable.